# visual basic 2010 express: Reading Xml file from public repository

Tags: vb.net, uri, xmlreader

I keep getting the following error when trying to parse data from tags from a public xml document.

> XmlException was unhandled Cannot open
>   'http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml'. The Uri parameter must
>   be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight
>   application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an
>   arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content
>   using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Here is the section of code I am editing:

```
Dim unmEventXml As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
Do While unmEventXml.Read()
    If unmEventXml.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso unmEventXml.Name = "summary" Then
        Me.Items.Add(New ItemViewModel() With {.LineOne = unmEventXml.Value, .LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", .LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu"})
    Else
        unmEventXml.Read()
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the exception message? That would be a good place to start :-)

> ...
>   If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

So just use a `WebClient` to download the xml file:

```
Dim client = New WebClient()
Dim stream = client.OpenRead("http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml")
Dim unmEventXml = XmlReader.Create(stream)
Do While unmEventXml.Read()
    ... Do your stuff ...
Loop
```

Comment: Dim client = New WebClient()
        Dim stream = client.OpenReadAsync("http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml")
        Dim unmEventXml = XmlReader.Create(stream)

Comment: I added those lines and They came up with errors. The first one is on the OpenRead. The error is Value of type 'String' cannont be converted to 'system.uri' so I added this code    ' Dim myUri As New Uri(strUrl)
        ' Dim client = New WebClient()
        '  Dim stream As StreamReader = client.OpenReadAsync(myUri)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to read my data!
 Dim filePathUnm As String = "http://datastore.unm.edu/events/events.xml"

```
        Dim rs As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
        rs.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        rs.IgnoreWhitespace = True
        Dim unmEventXml As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(filePathUnm), rs)
```

Thank you for the response Dominic Kexel.